# Call Jquery function after Drupal ajax update

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I have an e-commerce "add to cart" form on a Drupal 7 site.

[Development site can be found here](http://lilyandme1x9cfwwcfen.devcloud.acquia-sites.com/midi-skirt-linen-geo-lm1070)

I am displaying sizes of clothes as radio buttons.

When the user clicks on a size, I use jquery to add a wrapper class so that I can highlight the selected option.
The first time the user clicks on the size, the jquery fires and it gets the orange background I've set - but only briefly. I believe an ajax call is refreshing the controls and it's losing the wrapper class.
Clicking on the same size again makes the class stick.

My Jquery is simple:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click','.commerce-add-to-cart .form-radios input',function(){
        $(this.parentNode).removeClass('radio-checked');
        $(this.parentNode).addClass('radio-checked');
    });
  });   
})(jQuery);
```

So, my question is - how can I re-call my jquery function after the ajax has fired ?
Is there a hook that I don't know of that gets fired after the ajax call, or is there some kind of Jquery command that might help?
I've tried .setTimeout , .pause and a couple of other variations without success.

Comment: you can use `ajaxStop` https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/ , this allow you to know when all ajax query of the page is complete and then execute what you want second time after all (use parameters to catch your ajax) OR you can use `ajaxComplete `ajaxComplete https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/ , let you handle after each ajax complete

Answer (score 1):

You should be using drupal behaviors for your javascript.
Using Drupal behaviors, your code would look like:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myCustomStuff = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('body', context).on('click','.commerce-add-to-cart .form-radios input',function(){
        $(this.parentNode).removeClass('radio-checked');
        $(this.parentNode).addClass('radio-checked');
      });
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Basically, Drupal.behaviors is just a list of functions that Drupal will call whenever the page is loaded **or when an ajax call is completed**.

The first argument sent to the function "context" is the dom that that has been loaded, the full dom if you just loaded the page, but if an ajax function just returned a new form, then that form dom is what is sent as "context" to the function.

The second argument sent to the function "settings" is the Drupal.settings js object, this is used to send values from php to js.

It sounds like you may need a refresher on [javascript in Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/managing-javascript-in-drupal-7) and [this may help with behaviors](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/understanding-javascript-behaviors-in-drupal).

Also, The event listener might not work with the 'context' written like you have it now.
Maybe change:

```
$('body', context).on('click','.commerce-add-to-cart .form-radios input',function(){
```

to

```
$('.commerce-add-to-cart .form-radios', context).click(function(){
```

What I have posted above is how to properly do javascript in Drupal 7, but I'm not sure if it will fix your problem as it is hard to tell without knowing exactly how your form is working.
If you want wrappers around parts of forms depending on what is selected and it uses ajax, you might be better off adding the classes to the form components in a [form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x)